# Time varying magnetic field and faradays law of induction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, relativity, electromagnetic-induction

According to faraday's law we say that , whenever a magnetic field varies with time it creates an "electric field" .

But I do not understand , how can a time varying magnetic field produce electric field. What's the mechanism behind it?? 
I have also read on internet that due to Lorentz transformation a magnetic field creates a an electric field but , why does a change in reference frame turn a magnetic field into an electric field
And , also a time varying magnetic field creates an electric field in matter like conductors and also in empty space , how can there be an electric field in empty space where there are no charges
I want to know the reason in terms of Relativity or quantum mechanics
Thank you

Comment: It is because space is not separate from time. They are linked. Everything that happens in space, happens in time too, and vice-versa. Electric and magnetic fields are spatial and temporal manifestations of the same thing - the electromagnetic field.

Comment: @Andrei Geanta.  How is that related to the reason for creation of electric field by a time varying magnetic field?

Comment: I am afraid this is a misconception. There is a big difference between a field and a wave. A field is called "static", but it also can move slower than light. A wave moves with the speed of light. A moving electric field (charges) can generate a static magnetic field (magnet). A moving magnetic field cannot generate a (static) electric field, but only a wave. In QFT, a wave is just photons flying away. They can interact with remote charges as if by applying electric and magnetic fields, but they are really a wave. So you are correct, a static electric field cannot be produces without charges.

Comment: @safesphere. How does a time varying magnetic field generate electric field? What is the mechanism? That's my main question.

Comment: It doesn't. Read my previous comment. A varying magnetic field generates an electromagnetic wave, not a field. A field and a wave are not the same thing. A wave consists of real photons, a field does not. Furthermore, you cannot have a varying magnetic field without charges. So the wave actually is created by the varying electric field of the moving charges while a magnetic field is always static (meaning slower than light).

Comment: I am currently studying faradays laws and electromagnetic induction, and my book says that a varying magnetic field produces an electric field which is non conservative and responsible for current. But you are saying that it doesn't create an electric field. Then what is the reason behind induced current. Why current is induced by a varying magnetic field

Comment: The bottom line, the "mechanism" you are asking about, is that moving charges emit photons and these photons interact with remote charges. Mathematically you can see this as alternating electric and magnetic fields flying with the speed of light, but in reality it is photons. There are no fields without charges. Charges moving in space create a magnetic field. Charges moving in time create an electric field. So, depending on your speed relative to charges, the electric field becomes magnetic or magnetic becomes electric, but both are produced by moving charges.

Comment: It does not create a field, but it does create a wave, which is not static. Saying this differently, the current is created by electrons in the conductor absorbing incoming photons. The photons carry energy that converts to the electrical energy of moving electrons. Classical and quantum electromagnetism are not easily mixed together. While studying the classical theory you are better off by just taking it at the face value. So don't sweat it, just assume that what the book says is correct. You'll sort out these deep little details later after you become an expert in the Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: I believe, I have explained this repeatedly in my comments above. If they are still unclear, then let's hope someone would post an answer explaining this in a different way that you would find easier to understand. Sorry I don't normally chat. Good luck!

Comment: @Safesphere , according to you when I increase the current in solenoid, there is in an increase in electric field, so photons are emitted and these photons are responsible for induced currents in another coil . Also when there is decrease in the current, again it emits photons which responsible for induced currents. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, it is the deeper quantum view of this. However it is not productive to mix quantum and classical views. I would suggest taking a note of this intuition for a deeper understanding, but not try replacing with it the classical interpretation. Just study it the way it is in the book for now.

Comment: @safesphere you say "Charges moving in time create an electric field." Since everything with a rest mass (like a charge) is moving in the time dimension (even if it does not move in space), a charge (even a static) always creates an electric field, correct?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, a charge always creates an electric field. We can make its magnetic field zero by making the speed zero. However, it is impossible to make the electric field of a charge zero, because we cannot stop time. As the speed of the charge approaches the speed of light, its time moves slower and the electric field decreases. However, as you said, a massive particle cannot achieve the speed of light, so the electric field is never zero: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425925/where-does-the-magnetic-field-energy-come-from-in-case-of-a-charged-particle-mo/426044#426044

Comment: A magnetic field is created by the relative motion of charge.

Answer (score 1):

I distinguish two good questions. Q1 is about Faraday's law and Q2 about field transformation. First Q2. E and B are components of an antisymmetric rank 2 field tensor. The values of E and B therefore depend on the reference frame. This is no different from velocity and energy, which as also depend on the reference frame . As to Q1, the rotation of B and the time derivative of E are two ways to write down the exact same thing, $\partial_t \vec \nabla \times \vec A$.

Answer (score 0):

Electric and magnetic fields are not completely separate independent entities. They are just components of a single field: electromagnetic field. This can be seen in the [electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor). Components depend on frame of reference, even though the physical object (electromagnetic field) is the same. What looks like a pure electric field in one frame of reference, can look like electric and magnetic field in another frame.

From that you can see that electric field is not literally "created" by magnetic field. They are parts of the same object.

Change of reference frame turns magnetic field into electric field for the same reason, why change of reference frame turns the coordinate $x=0$ into $x\ne0$.

Comment: A perhaps more accessible explanation is that we have three experimental facts: (1) stationary charges produce electric fields, (2) moving charges produce magnetic fields, (3) there is no absolute reference frame anywhere that we know of.
What you find from (3) is that whether you think a charge is moving or not is a function of whether or not you are moving.  In the frame where you think the charge is at rest, there is only an electric field, but in the frame where you think the charge is moving, there is both an electric and magnetic field.  There must be a deeper relationship between them.